# DB2 create table fail

Tags: database, db2, create-table

I create a table with Liqibase on our test Databse we have no Problem to create following table:

```
CREATE TABLE ICEM_DEP.T_APP_UNIT_ENV_INST_OBJ (
  ENVIRONMENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  INSTANCE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL, 
  APP_UNIT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current timestamp(0), 
  LAST_CHANGE_DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current timestamp(0), 
  CREATION_USER INTEGER NOT NULL,
  LAST_CHANGE_USER INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  ACTION_FLAG VARCHAR(1)
)
```

If I run this statement on the costumer database the is following Error:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=(;LT current
>   timestamp;DEFAULT, DRIVER=4.13.127

Any Suggestion?

Comment: DB2 for what? LUW, System z, i5/OS?

Answer (score 1):

did you try with

```
CREATION_DATE TIMESTAMP WITH DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP,
LAST_CHANGE_DATE TIMESTAMP WITH DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP,
```

Answer (score 0):

The format for passing the lowest possible value to the  Timestamp Function is

Either

```
TIMESTAMP('0001-01-01',0)
```

or

```
TIMESTAMP('0001-01-01-00.00.00.00000')
```